# Mapreduce Pipe: Implementing cleanup in reducer

Tags: c++, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I am trying to implement a cleanup method of reducer in C++.
I tried following test job.

```
class WordCountReducer : public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
public:
  WordCountReducer(HadoopPipes::TaskContext& context) {}
  // Reduce function
  void reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext& context) {
    //dont emit anything in reducer
  }

  void cleanup(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext& context) {
    //emit key and value as 1
    context.emit(context.getInputKey(), HadoopUtils::toString(1));
  }
};
```

Although the job runs successfully, it does not print anything in the output file. Doing exactly the same thing but emitting in reducers works perfectly.

Used this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/mapreduce-user/10cdhsnxhb/setup-and-cleanup-methods) for java implementation which works like a charm!

I am an amateur with C++ and pipes.

Comment: did you try emit a static key instead of context.getInputKey()?

Comment: Yes, sir. I did that. Not working